# What is the correct way to change password in Angular-Strongloop app?

Tags: angularjs, strongloop

I have looked through docs, SO and the interwebs, unable to find an example that shows how the password for a User can be changed with a Strongloop backend and an app using the AngularJS API generated by slc. Highly appreciate pointers in the right direction.

**Update**
I'm not looking for the reset password which is the case the password is forgotten. 
I'm looking for a legitimate way to change where the old pass as well as new pass needs to be provided and the old pass will be validated before the new pass is set.

Comment: a quick search of the StrongLoop API documentation brings http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#user-resetpassword.

Comment: @Claies that is not what I'm looking for, the reset password is in the case the password is forgotten. I'm looking for a legitimate change where the old pass as well as new pass needs to be provided and the old pass will be validated before the new pass is set. I'm adding this to the question to make it easier for people.

Comment: ok, so according to [the official sample source](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-faq-user-management/blob/master/server/boot/routes.js#L89), you can use `user.updateAttribute('password', req.body.password, function(err, user)`.

Comment: @Claies This is still an example of resetting the password, this would not be a secure way of validating a password change. This is not the standard way of changing a password. The user changing the password should know the old password.

Comment: yes, and if you read the documentation, it clearly states that you must be logged in with the user to have `updateAttribute` rights for that user.  This is definitely secure; the user logs in, has a token, then you can send them to a form that asks for the new password, confirm new password, and send that to the server.  If it's a different user trying to execute `updateAttribute`, the function will fail.

Comment: @Claies yes that's fine, but it doesn't address the situation where someone gets hold of a computer with a user logged in and then changes the password. In this case the user gets locked out and then has to reset the password, but that is definitely not desirable because the attacker could have already done several other things like changing the email which is used to reset the password. This is why secure sites will always require you to enter the old password before changing the new password. I hope this explains why I want to enforce the user to enter the old password.

Comment: so then you just have to add the current password confirmation field on your form, and validate the password before you call the update.  I don't know how else to answer your questions without writing the module for you.

Comment: That's where strongloop makes it a bit difficult, it has it's own mechanism for  doing user management, so I was looking for a solution within the framework, not having to extend it

Comment: I don't think this is outside their framework, honestly, as I was able to find examples of these kinds of functions inside their sample sources; seems this is exactly the way they do it in the official apps.

Comment: well I think there' s a misunderstanding between reset and change password. reset password is with an email to the user, change password should not have the user leaving the website ideally, hope that makes sense

Comment: No confusion; it's quite easy to make a service in angular that first confirms the current password and then calls updateAttributes with the new password in a single call on one page...

Comment: as you made clarifications to your concerns in the comments, I was able to continue to dig in to the API and find snippets of code that seem to demonstrate what you want to achieve; that being said, I would consider a different API if you have major security concerns, since it does seem as though there is a lack of documentation of key features, and potentially some security flaws (for example, no mention of a password hashing scheme).

Comment: They do have a password hashing scheme, so that concern is alleviated. Your prior comment definitely helps, I think I'll take that route, do a login first and if that succeeds then change the password. Thanks! I'll post the answer once I've implemented so it may help someone else in a similar situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to log the user in again, simply run the hasPassword method on the User to compare the passwords and if true, update the attribute

something like this...

    `if(user.hasPassword(req.body.oldPassword)) {
        user.updateAttribute('password', req.body.password ....
    }`

https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#user-prototype-haspassword

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the application user Model is called `MyUserModel` and inherits from the built-in model `User`.

You have two options :

1. If you can only work on the AngularJS / client side.

   Use the `update` remote method (PUT request) on MyUserModel and just specify

   `{ "password":"...newpassword..."}`

   in the body.

   However, it probably is more convenient to have a specific remote method than this trick in order to enforce security policy on the new password.
2. If you can work on the NodeJS / LoopBack server side.

   Here is my "full" solution to implement a specific updatePassword remote method in a LoopBack / StrongLoop - IBM project.
   Please verify that the `loopback-datasource-juggler` package has a higher or equal version than 2.45.1 (`npm list loopback-datasource-juggler`).

"my-user-model.js"

```
module.exports = function (MyUserModel) {

...

MyUserModel.updatePassword = function (ctx, emailVerify, oldPassword, newPassword, cb) {
  var newErrMsg, newErr;
  try {
    this.findOne({where: {id: ctx.req.accessToken.userId, email: emailVerify}}, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        cb(err);
      } else if (!user) {
        newErrMsg = "No match between provided current logged user and email";
        newErr = new Error(newErrMsg);
        newErr.statusCode = 401;
        newErr.code = 'LOGIN_FAILED_EMAIL';
        cb(newErr);
      } else {
        user.hasPassword(oldPassword, function (err, isMatch) {
          if (isMatch) {

            // TODO ...further verifications should be done here (e.g. non-empty new password, complex enough password etc.)...

            user.updateAttributes({'password': newPassword}, function (err, instance) {
              if (err) {
                cb(err);
              } else {
                cb(null, true);
              }
            });
          } else {
            newErrMsg = 'User specified wrong current password !';
            newErr = new Error(newErrMsg);
            newErr.statusCode = 401;
            newErr.code = 'LOGIN_FAILED_PWD';
            return cb(newErr);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(err);
    cb(err);
  }
};

MyUserModel.remoteMethod(
  'updatePassword',
  {
    description: "Allows a logged user to change his/her password.",
    http: {verb: 'put'},
    accepts: [
      {arg: 'ctx', type: 'object', http: {source: 'context'}},
      {arg: 'emailVerify', type: 'string', required: true, description: "The user email, just for verification"},
      {arg: 'oldPassword', type: 'string', required: true, description: "The user old password"},
      {arg: 'newPassword', type: 'string', required: true, description: "The user NEW password"}
    ],
    returns: {arg: 'passwordChange', type: 'boolean'}
  }
);

...
};
```

"my-user-model.json"

```
{
   "name": "MyUserModel",
   "base": "User",

   ...

   "acls": [
     ...
     {
       "comment":"allow authenticated users to change their password",
       "accessType": "EXECUTE",
       "property":"updatePassword",
       "principalType": "ROLE",
       "principalId": "$authenticated",
       "permission": "ALLOW"
     }
   ...
   ],
   ...
}
```